# The script will not align to the right of the page

Tags: javascript

How do I align the text in the following script to align right of the page. Screen shot attached.

```
function init() {
$('.ey-flight-selection-panel>div>h3').after('<div id="covidmsg"><div>ⓘ يتضمن حجزك إجراء فحص كوفيد-19 (بي سي آر) قبل السفر من أبوظبي للسفر حتى 31 ديسمبر 2020. سيتم فرض رسوم بقيمة 150 درهماً إماراتياً إذا قمت بتغيير أو إلغاء حجزك خلال 96 ساعة من موعد الرحلة. <a href=\'https://www.etihad.com/en-ae/travel-updates/flights-from-abu-dhabi/\' target=\'_blank\'>اقرأ المزيد</a></br></br></div></div>');
}

var i = 1;
setTimeout(function run() {
//console.log(i + ":hello number");
if (i < 10) {
setTimeout(run, 500);
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
if ($('#covidmsg').length < 1) {
init()
}
}
}
if (i >= 10) {
//console.log("Task Done");
}
i++;
}, 100)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72eME.png)

Comment: I think it depends of code editor, can you provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

Update your css to include:

```
#covidmsg {direction: rtl;}
```